tcpdump on wifi interface shows BSSID of the access point as source address/MAC
I am trying to understand traffic as shown by tcpdump on my wifi interface (MAC_PC) looking at my regular traffic coming from an access point (MAC_AP), linked by an Ethernet cable to my router (MAC_RT).
Most of the traffic to my laptop comes from the router (source address shown by the -e flag is MAC_RT) but some frames are shown as coming from the access point (source address is MAC_AP = BBSID).
My understanding of the 802.11 frames, when using an AP, is that they will have all 3 addresses, with source address and destination address always being MAC_PC and MAC_RT (depending on the direction of the traffic) and MAC_AP/BSSID only being in a receiver or transmitter address (also depending on the direction of the traffic).
The BSSID would then not be shown to tcpdump since it would only be in the headers of the 802.11 frames which I think are removed at a lower level:

On Linux and macOS, you can only get 802.11 headers in monitor mode.

https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN
How can some frames come from the AP (with source address = BSSID)? Could it be some mix up in tcpdump, at lower level, or the AP creating new frames (fragmentation settings?).
Edit: Please see some tcpdump of a wireguard connection, with the same issue (so this cannot depend on the stage of a TCP connection or the content, etc.). rt = router, pc = laptop, ap = access point. 123.123.123.123 is my own wireguard server (of course, a different address). So the access point's MAC address starts to appear as the source in the middle of normal router - laptop traffic.
23:06:53.050391 rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 122: 123.123.123.123.51820 > 192.168.51.4.51820: UDP, length 80
23:06:53.055216 rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1466: 123.123.123.123.51820 > 192.168.51.4.51820: UDP, length 1424
23:06:53.055530 pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc > rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 122: 192.168.51.4.51820 > 123.123.123.123.51820: UDP, length 80
23:06:53.056392 rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1466: 123.123.123.123.51820 > 192.168.51.4.51820: UDP, length 1424
23:06:53.074237 rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1466: 123.123.123.123.51820 > 192.168.51.4.51820: UDP, length 1424
23:06:53.074576 pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc > rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 122: 192.168.51.4.51820 > 123.123.123.123.51820: UDP, length 80
23:06:53.077497 ap:ap:ap:ap:ap:ap > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1466: 123.123.123.123.51820 > 192.168.51.4.51820: UDP, length 1424
23:06:53.079489 ap:ap:ap:ap:ap:ap > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1466: 123.123.123.123.51820 > 192.168.51.4.51820: UDP, length 1424
23:06:53.079491 ap:ap:ap:ap:ap:ap > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1466: 123.123.123.123.51820 > 192.168.51.4.51820: UDP, length 1424
23:06:53.079491 ap:ap:ap:ap:ap:ap > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1466: 123.123.123.123.51820 > 192.168.51.4.51820: UDP, length 1424
23:06:53.079492 ap:ap:ap:ap:ap:ap > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1466: 123.123.123.123.51820 > 192.168.51.4.51820: UDP, length 1424
23:06:53.079493 ap:ap:ap:ap:ap:ap > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 122: 123.123.123.123.51820 > 192.168.51.4.51820: UDP, length 80
23:06:53.079783 pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc > rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 122: 192.168.51.4.51820 > 123.123.123.123.51820: UDP, length 80
23:06:53.081494 ap:ap:ap:ap:ap:ap > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1466: 123.123.123.123.51820 > 192.168.51.4.51820: UDP, length 1424
23:06:53.081496 ap:ap:ap:ap:ap:ap > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1466: 123.123.123.123.51820 > 192.168.51.4.51820: UDP, length 1424
23:06:53.081496 rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 122: 123.123.123.123.51820 > 192.168.51.4.51820: UDP, length 80
23:06:53.081497 rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1466: 123.123.123.123.51820 > 192.168.51.4.51820: UDP, length 1424
23:06:53.081497 rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1466: 123.123.123.123.51820 > 192.168.51.4.51820: UDP, length 1424
23:06:53.081498 rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1466: 123.123.123.123.51820 > 192.168.51.4.51820: UDP, length 1424
23:06:53.081864 pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc > rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 122: 192.168.51.4.51820 > 123.123.123.123.51820: UDP, length 80

The only pattern I could find which is is also the case here, is that this seems to happen more often than not with data content and when there's heavy traffic, eg. whatsapp like the below example, or test on fast.com, etc.
Edit 2: The access point is a TL-WA801N. I swapped it with a netgear access point (higher capacity) and have not yet noticed the same sort of issues.
22:42:24.371937 pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc > rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 54: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 8391, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.51.4.48534 > 157.240.201.60.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x5af4 (incorrect -> 0x7f76), seq 5055, ack 10924, win 442, length 0
22:42:24.372108 pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc > rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 54: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 8392, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.51.4.48534 > 157.240.201.60.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x5af4 (incorrect -> 0x7f1a), seq 5055, ack 11016, win 442, length 0
22:42:24.408006 pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc > rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 130: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56970, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 116)
    192.168.51.4.38612 > 157.240.201.60.https: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5b40 (incorrect -> 0xc712), seq 15494:15570, ack 2734614, win 14400, length 76
22:42:24.408389 pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc > rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 130: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56971, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 116)
    192.168.51.4.38612 > 157.240.201.60.https: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5b40 (incorrect -> 0x5767), seq 15570:15646, ack 2734614, win 14400, length 76
22:42:24.569867 pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc > rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 130: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56972, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 116)
    192.168.51.4.38612 > 157.240.201.60.https: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5b40 (incorrect -> 0x5767), seq 15570:15646, ack 2734614, win 14400, length 76
22:42:24.579793 ap:ap:ap:ap:ap:ap > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 89: (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 34814, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 75)
    157.240.201.60.https > 192.168.51.4.38612: Flags [P.], cksum 0xa596 (correct), seq 2734614:2734649, ack 15570, win 560, length 35
22:42:24.579793 ap:ap:ap:ap:ap:ap > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 89: (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 34815, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 75)
    157.240.201.60.https > 192.168.51.4.38612: Flags [P.], cksum 0xc734 (correct), seq 2734649:2734684, ack 15646, win 560, length 35
22:42:24.579793 ap:ap:ap:ap:ap:ap > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 336: (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 34816, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 322)
    157.240.201.60.https > 192.168.51.4.38612: Flags [P.], cksum 0xd806 (correct), seq 2734684:2734966, ack 15646, win 560, length 282
22:42:24.579793 ap:ap:ap:ap:ap:ap > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 12361: (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 34817, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 12347)
    157.240.201.60.https > 192.168.51.4.38612: Flags [P.], cksum 0x8b07 (incorrect -> 0x7b5a), seq 2734966:2747273, ack 15646, win 560, length 12307
22:42:24.579870 ap:ap:ap:ap:ap:ap > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 309: (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 34827, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 295)
    157.240.201.60.https > 192.168.51.4.38612: Flags [P.], cksum 0xd80b (correct), seq 2747273:2747528, ack 15646, win 560, length 255
22:42:24.579870 ap:ap:ap:ap:ap:ap > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 10774: (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 34828, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 10760)
    157.240.201.60.https > 192.168.51.4.38612: Flags [.], cksum 0x84d4 (incorrect -> 0x8a55), seq 2747528:2758248, ack 15646, win 560, length 10720
22:42:24.579920 pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc > rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 54: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56973, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.51.4.38612 > 157.240.201.60.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x5af4 (incorrect -> 0x982a), seq 15646, ack 2758248, win 14216, length 0
22:42:24.579981 ap:ap:ap:ap:ap:ap > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 6150: (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 34836, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 6136)
    157.240.201.60.https > 192.168.51.4.38612: Flags [P.], cksum 0x72c4 (incorrect -> 0x4cc6), seq 2758248:2764344, ack 15646, win 560, length 6096
22:42:24.579991 pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc > rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 54: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56974, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.51.4.38612 > 157.240.201.60.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x5af4 (incorrect -> 0x8089), seq 15646, ack 2764344, win 14169, length 0
22:42:24.641880 rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 34841, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    157.240.201.60.https > 192.168.51.4.38612: Flags [.], cksum 0xa851 (correct), seq 2764344, ack 15646, win 560, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {15570:15646}], length 0
22:42:24.980498 pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc > rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 143: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 8393, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 129)
    192.168.51.4.48534 > 157.240.201.60.https: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5b4d (incorrect -> 0xe2cf), seq 5055:5144, ack 11016, win 442, length 89
22:42:24.980628 pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc > rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 232: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 8394, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 218)
    192.168.51.4.48534 > 157.240.201.60.https: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5ba6 (incorrect -> 0xd4d8), seq 5144:5322, ack 11016, win 442, length 178
22:42:24.981029 pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc > rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1300: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 8395, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1286)
    192.168.51.4.48534 > 157.240.201.60.https: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5fd2 (incorrect -> 0x6f00), seq 5322:6568, ack 11016, win 442, length 1246
22:42:24.986793 pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc > rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1565: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 8396, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1551)
    192.168.51.4.48534 > 157.240.201.60.https: Flags [P.], cksum 0x60db (incorrect -> 0xd7f8), seq 6568:8079, ack 11016, win 442, length 1511
22:42:25.058796 rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 60: (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 18602, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    157.240.201.60.https > 192.168.51.4.48534: Flags [.], cksum 0x7e83 (correct), seq 11016, ack 5322, win 326, length 0
22:42:25.058796 rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 60: (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 18603, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    157.240.201.60.https > 192.168.51.4.48534: Flags [.], cksum 0x7454 (correct), seq 11016, ack 7908, win 347, length 0
22:42:25.146329 rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 127: (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 18604, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 113)
    157.240.201.60.https > 192.168.51.4.48534: Flags [P.], cksum 0x520b (correct), seq 11016:11089, ack 7908, win 347, length 73
22:42:25.146359 pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc > rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 54: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 8398, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.51.4.48534 > 157.240.201.60.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x5af4 (incorrect -> 0x7301), seq 8079, ack 11089, win 442, length 0
22:42:25.148170 rt:rt:rt:rt:rt:rt > pc:pc:pc:pc:pc:pc, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 127: (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 18605, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 113)
    157.240.201.60.https > 192.168.51.4.48534: Flags [P.], cksum 0x800e (correct), seq 11089:11162, ack 7908, win 347, length 73


Please edit your question to include some of the tcpdump output. It’s hard to tell what you are seeing. Maybe beacons?

Thanks, done, let me know if you'd like to see more, but that's a good example I think as this happens with both UDP and TCP packets so that removes some possible TCP causes?

What type of access point is this?  If we could see the packet contents, it would be easier tell what is happening.

I included the information, thanks!
